# Passing arguments on object initialization via terminal

Tags: php, bash, terminal

I'm trying to pass arguments to a PHP script that needs to be executed on the terminal.

test.class.php

```
class test {

        // ID's param for query thread
        private $IDsOne;
        private $IDsTwo;

        /*  __construct
         *  Constructor called on object initilization
        */
        public function __construct($IDsOne, $IDsTwo) {
              $this->$IDsOne = $IDsOne;
              $this->$IDsTwo = $IDsTwo;
              $this->output();
        }

        public function output() {
              // check if object attributes set?
              var_dump($this->IDsOne);
              var_dump($this->IDsTwo);
        }
}
```

on terminal:

```
> php test.class.php 0 100
```

I'm trying to pass the arguments "0" and "100" to the class constructor. I'm current not getting any errors, or returned data.

Comment: CLI arguments are accessible through `$argv` ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php))

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't automatically invoke the constructor when a class definition is called from the command line. You need to add some procedural code at the bottom of the script to create an instance of the class, like this:

```
$test = new test($argv[1], $argv[2]);
```

Command line arguments are listed into the `$argv` global variable, starting with the name of the script itself in argument zero.

(You've also got a minor syntax error here:

```
$this->$IDsOne = $IDsOne;
$this->$IDsTwo = $IDsTwo;
```

which should be

```
$this->IDsOne = $IDsOne;
$this->IDsTwo = $IDsTwo;
```

The first way will initialise dynamic properties based on the value of the two inputs, rather than the two class member variables.)